# United States Law: Who would the law hold most accountable in this scenario?

Tags: united-states

Let's say in a scenario, Organization X wants something illegal done. Organization X employs Person A in their organization to do the illegal task. Person A cannot do this task by themselves, so they hire Person B to do it.

Person B gets caught doing the illegal task and tells the police that all they know is that Person A paid them to do it. Person A says all they know is that Organization X told them to do it.

Under the U.S. legal system, who gets into the most trouble?

Comment: Depends on what the acts are, and if this could be RICO (like, at some *other* point A asks X to do something for him)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments, this is a RICO case and Org X is criminally liable for the same illegal actions that were committed by Persons A and B.   Depending on the nature of Org X, they would likely see the most punishment as the prosector would likely reduce the charges of A and B for coorperation in testifying against X (though likely between the two, B would get a more favorable deal than A since he came clean first.).   This might change depending on if Org X is say a corperation, which can be charged as a legal person for a crime, but cannot be jailed like an actual human person.  Thus, if A or B has a deal that results in some prison time, X would likely only have to pay a fine if found criminally guilty (and may lose certain liscesnses where applicable) which may not amount to much beyond a slap on the wrist if Org X is sufficently large enough.

Comment: *can be* RICO, even likely, but too little info to make sure it *is* RICO